# How to Retrieve Data using Checkbox in Eclipse using Java

Tags: java, database, swing, jcheckbox

Hello can someone guide me on how to write a coding if I want to retrieve data using checkbox. I did place the checkbox but I feel blank on how to do the next step. And Im using Eclipse with mySql. Please respond here thank you.

[this is the output once the database mySql has successfully connected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50Q5B.png)

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a listener for the checkbox
2. Then use JDBC library to connect to database. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/overview/index.html
3. Finally format and display the data in any container like a table in the UI.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! But how to retrieve checked values from database ? It seems that I have problem with that too

Comment: @6298fdmz: Use a boolean column for your database table.  Checked -> true, unchecked -> false.

Comment: use where condition in the query to filter the values from DB, filter using the value obtained in the checkbox event.